# How to determine where method was called

Tags: java, stack-trace

I provide an API and need to know, where methods of the API were invoked. I could of cause use reflection or the thread stacktrace, but that would include a lot of runtime cost.

I do not need the exact class name, a unique reference per invocation would be sufficient. In C I would normally use the preprocessor to automatically add `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` to the method invocation.

Is there a method in Java (besides code generation) to get a unique caller identification with low runtime cost?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26425049/how-to-get-a-unique-method-identifier

Comment: Just wondering: what problem do you intend to solve here?

Comment: May be have a look at AspectJ and set up a join point whenever your API is called?

Comment: @matthelliwell "besides code generation" eliminates AspectJ.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with AspectJ: I'm not against byte code generation, but against source code generation

Comment: @GhostCat I have a remote method invocation that might throw an exception but asynchronous. Now I want the debugging information where the method was invoked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would be to have a cached Throwable which is passed in.

```
class StackPoint {
    Throwable stack;
    public Throwable getStack() {
        if (stack == null)
            stack = new Throwable();
        return stack;
    }
}

public void methodToCall(StackPoint sp) {
    Throwable t = sp.getStack();

}


static final StackPoint one = new StackPoint();

methodToCall(one); // Have to remember to give each line a different StackPoint.
```

Note: if the method which calls this caller changes, you only record the first one ever.

---

There isn't a standard pattern and it is likely that if you want this to be efficient the caller will need to pass a unique id.  The closest you can do is use is a lambda.

```
public void methodToCall(Runnable run) {
    Class id = run.getClass();

}
```

You can call it like this

```
methodtoCall(()->{});
```

This will create a different class for each place it is called, even if it appears multiple times on the same line. It creates no garbage as it reuses the same object each time.  You could make this shorter with

```
void methodToCall(IntFunction fun) {

}
```

and call

```
methodToCall(a->1);
```

Comment: While I cannot prohibit call sites passing the same argument twice this is a really nice solution. If the argument passed is unknown I will use the stacktrace to get the exact call site and otherwise using the cached information.

Comment: But counting on lambda's identity is wrong, isn't it?

Comment: @ooxi giving the caller code they can copy and paste without having to change manually, means they are less likely to mess with it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik it is possible in the future that lambdas which have the same code will be shared even if they are in different places, however this is not what Java 8 or 9 do currently. The longer they leave it, the less likely this will happen.

Comment: A pragmatic view indeed :) They were quite serious about this point, though.

Comment: @GhostCat it creates the classes at runtime which could be an issue, but not in your deployment.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik A problem they might face is the debug information is always different as it comes from different lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

As something asynchroneous is involved, split the call up, and let the API return the ID.

```
Ticket callTicket = api.call(params);
Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName(), Level.FINE, callTicket);
Result result = callTicket.get();
```

Above having a result returned (synchroneously) is probably not the case with your code. Your code will get the result delived elsewhere. But that could be a ticket system too.

Comment: But how can I determine whether or not a new Ticket should be returned without inspecting the stacktrace?

Comment: Every call also at the same class and line draws a new ticket from the API. To log for instance. On an asynchrone exception, the ticket is known, and one can search in the logs. Certainly a different approach and perspective.

Comment: I certainly prefer your solution since it does not cutter client's code with technical details. Nethertheless I'll keep the answer from @PeterLawrey as the accepted one since it does resolve the question more directly.